# TextArea on pop up box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display an alert box or pop up box  with my own form , like,  there should be textarea on the form and 2 buttons , proceed and cancel , how can I do display that and take actions based on the text area text and button which is clicked , How can I do this?

e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt

Here there is a textbox , instead of that , I want a textAreawith 2 buttons , Proceed and Cancel.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible out of the box with [prompt()][1].


  [1]: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/prompt.htm

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's possible ..
figured it out with little more research

http://jsfiddle.net/Xtreu/297/

with overlay:  http://jsfiddle.net/Xtreu/270/

HTML:

```
<div id="confirmBox">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="confirmBox">
        <div class="message"></div>
        <span class="button yes">Yes</span>
        <span class="button no">No</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = this;
        doConfirm("Are you sure?", function yes() {
            form.submit();
        }, function no() {
            // do nothing
        });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
#confirmBox
{
    display: none;
}
.overlay
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.confirmBox
{
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    padding: 6px 8px 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}
#confirmBox .button {
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#confirmBox .button:hover
{
    background-color: #ddd;
}
#confirmBox .message
{
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is [prompt()](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form), you can't add `textarea` or `other elements` in it.

You can use [jquery.dialog()](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) for this.